# Format UITextField Text

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have a UITextfield to enter a card number, of length 16. But i need to format the pin number as 1234 **** *** *** at the time of entering. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: is it ok if there will be spaces to separate numbers?

Answer (score 1):

**Do you mean u want the digits to be asterisk?**

if yes just go on to your xib file click the textfield

and go to inspector attributes and check the secure button.

hope thats what u want

Comment: +1 You can also do this programmatically. Check the `UITextField` docs.

Comment: if the input is 1234567891234567. i want to replace it as 1234 **** **** ****

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding an observer to UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification; every time that notification is fired, you can re-format the input.

Answer (score 0):

if it is ok, thet there will be spaces to separate numbers:

```
[text addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldEditing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

- (IBAction)textFieldEditing:(id)sender {
    //separate string of your TextField text and add spaces where you whant
    [sender setText:(NSString *)]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read [this sample code on GitHub](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UIKeyInput-UITextInput-Sample).

It implements the `UIKeyInput` protocol to produce a custom input view.